# Removing 'nil's from a column using transpose

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a nested array:

```
arr = [[1,nil,2,3,4], [2,nil,4,5,6], [6,nil,3,3,5]]
```

Any elements at the same index in the subarrays that are `nil` across the array must be removed. The second index in all subarrays have `nil`.

I did this:

```
collection = arr.transpose.select(&:any?).transpose
# => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 5, 6], [6, 3, 3, 5]]
```

It works for me, albiet I am using `transpose` twice. Could this technique lead to data getting mixed up? It looks fool proof to me.

Comment: What is the return value if `arr = [[1,nil], [2,nil], [nil,nil]]`? `arr = [[nil,nil], [nil, nil]]`? `arr = [[1,nil], [2,false]]`?

Comment: `arr.transpose.reject { |a| a.all?(&:nil?) }.transpose` is needed if the array may contain `false` and arguably reads better.

Comment: @CarySwoveland good point

Comment: Your code is wrong in the first place. It deletes any elements of the same subarray index that are `nil` in **at least one subarray**, not all.

Comment: In addition to @CarySwoveland's answer, you can also filter specific classes via `a.all?(NilClass)`

Comment: @sawa I do not see that happening. In example provided, all the nils of the related column are deleted in all the subarrays.

Comment: @Stefan, I don't understand. Can you elaborate? [Enumerable#all?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) optionally takes a block, but no argument. No?

Comment: @CarySwoveland the 2.5 version does: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

With the `nil`-vs-`false` caveat that @CarySwoveland noted in a comment, yes, your double-`transpose` is safe: it will only work on data that's rectangular to begin with, and it will produce equally-rectangular data as output. You're filtering out whole rows, so nothing can get misaligned.

While it's not *super* efficient, it's not too bad, and is far more expressive & readable than more direct looping & manipulation.